# Dynamic list changing with select input with HTMX and Alpine.js

Tags: htmx

I have a page where I render a list of items on load. I also have a select input that when the option changes I change a variable within the URL endpoint using Alpine.js reactive property.

```
<div x-data="{ selectedOption: 'title' }" hx-ext="client-side-templates">
<select id="selection" x-model="selectedOption" @change="console.log('Selected option:', selectedOption)" :hx-get="'{{ url('<front>') }}/api/v1/collection-items-per-term?tid=' + $store.globalStore.taxonomyTerm + '&sort_by='+ selectedOption +'&sort_order=DESC'" hx-trigger="load, change" hx-target="#responseDiv" hx-ext="debug" nunjucks-template="collection-items-taxonomy-hero-unit">
    <option value="title">Title</option>
    <option value="date">Date</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<div id="responseDiv"></div>
```

I have enabled the debug extension in the hx-get. I am also logging the selected option to be sure that it changes before the request. The very strange thing is that from the console log, I can see that the request is changing with the new selectedOption but I can see from the network tab the request is done to the URl with the old option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`hx-get`, `hx-post`, etc. get evaluated on load, once, and cannot be updated this way. You need to do it using an event like `htmx:beforeRequest` by changing the parameters, or it's easier to use `hx-vals` for the url parameters.

https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-vals/

Something like this:

```
hx-get="'{{ url('<front>') }}/api/v1/collection-items-per-term"
:hx-vals='{"tid": $store.globalStore.taxonomyTerm, "sort_by": selectedOption, "sort_order": "DESC"}'
```

Comment: Well, the answer was much simpler. I removed all reactivity of selectedOption and I just used name=sort_by in my select input. This is normally picked up by HTMX and is requested.